# How to count the correct answers in this C++ code

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am trying to run this code, where it will count how many correct answers the user made.

But I don't know how. I think I should use the `if` or nested `if`'s to do that. How can I do it?

This will ask for a user to input their correct answer, A, B, C, or D. Then I want to increment the n:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define p printf
#define s scanf

main () {
    int Ttl;
    char Ln, Mi, Fn,
         A1,   A2,  A3,  A4,  A5,  A6,  A7,  A8,  A9, A10,
         A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, A16, A17, A18, A19, A20;

    clrscr();

    p("\n)
    p("\n\nEnter your last name: ");
    s("%s", &Ln);
    p("\nEnter your middle initial: ");
    s("%s", &Mi);
    p("\nEnter your first name: ");
    s("%s", &Fn);
    p("\nType the corresponding letter to each question.");
    p("\n1.) Shortcut for'New Line'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + R          C. Ctrl + M ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + QC          D. Ctrl + KC ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A1);
    p("\n2.) Shortcut for'Up Arrow Key'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + Z          C. Ctrl + X ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + QC          D. Ctrl + E ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A2);
    p("\n3.) Shortcut for'Down Arrow Key'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + X          C. Ctrl + E ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + C          D. Ctrl + R ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A3);
    p("\n4.) Shortcut for'Scroll Down'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + X          C. Ctrl + R ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + E          D. Ctrl + Z ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A4);
    p("\n5.) Shortcut for'Page Up'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + K          C. Ctrl + R ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + Q          D. Ctrl + C ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A5);
    p("\n6.) Shortcut for'Page Down'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + Q          C. Ctrl + K ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + C          D. Ctrl + Z ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A6);
    p("\n7.) Shortcut for'Top of a File'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + KY          C. Ctrl + KC  ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + QC          D. Ctrl + QR ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A7);
    p("\n8.) Shortcut for'Bottom of a File'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + QC          C. Ctrl + KY ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + QS          D. Ctrl + KC ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A8);
    p("\n9.) Shortcut for'Copy Block'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + QY          C. Ctrl + KC ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + KY          D. Ctrl + QC ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A9);
    p("\n10.) Shortcut for'Delete Block'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + QR          C. Ctrl + QC ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + KC          D. Ctrl + KY ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A10);
    p("\n11.) Hot Keys Command 'Saves the file currently being edited'");
    p("\n  A. F6          C. F2 ");
    p("\n  B. F4          D. F9 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A11);
    p("\n12.) Hot Keys Command'Loads a File'");
    p("\n  A. F7          C. F1");
    p("\n  B. F3          D. F8");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A12);
    p("\n13.) Hot Keys Command'Compiles and link the program'");
    p("\n  A. F4          C. F3 ");
    p("\n  B. F2          D. F9 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A13);
    p("\n14.) Hot Keys Command'Compiles file to .obj file'");
    p("\n  A. Alt + F9          C. Alt + F5 ");
    p("\n  B. Alt + F2          D. Alt + F7 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A14);
    p("\n15.) Hot Keys Command'Next error'");
    p("\n  A. Alt + F4          C. Alt + F9 ");
    p("\n  B. Alt + F7          D. Alt + F8 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A15);
    p("\n16.) Hot Keys Command'Previous error'");
    p("\n  A. Alt + F7          C. Alt + F9 ");
    p("\n  B. Alt + F3          D. Alt + F1 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A16);
    p("\n17.) Hot Keys Command'Activates the file menu'");
    p("\n  A. Alt + E           C. Alt + C ");
    p("\n  B. Alt + F          D. Alt + O ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A17);
    p("\n18.) Hot Keys Command'Quit the Turbo C program'");
    p("\n  A. Alt + D          C. Alt + P ");
    p("\n  B. Alt + C          D. Alt + X ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A18);
    p("\n19.) Hot Keys Command'Runs the program'");
    p("\n  A. Ctrl + F3          C. Ctrl + F2 ");
    p("\n  B. Ctrl + F5          D. Ctrl + F9 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A19);
    p("\n20.) Hot Keys Command'Switches between windows'");
    p("\n  A. F2          C. F6 ");
    p("\n  B. F4          D. F8 ");
    p("\nAnswer: ");
    s("%s", A20);
    p("Thank you for answering the following question");
    p("\nCalculating correct answers. Please wait...");
    delay(5000);
    p("\nYour total correct answer is: ");
    p("\n\t\tEnd of the Program");

    getche();
}
```

Comment: array of structs with the loop is the better approach since it will allow you to have unlimited number of questions in your questionaire. btw, you need to use %c instead of %s in scanf because you are working with single char variables.

Comment: "in this c++ code" Where?

Comment: Don't `#define p printf`. Just use `printf` directly.

Comment: `s("%s",&Ln)`  - The longer my last name, the worse it's going to get for your program.  All of your `scanf` calls are fundamentally flawed and will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Whenever you are creating a set of variables like `A1`, .... `A20` then that is a classic hint you need to create an array and to use a loop to work over elements of that array.   Doing that would probably make your code 80% smaller, and easier to understand, while doing exactly the same thing.    And using macros like `#define p printf` or `#define s printf` achieves nothing except making code incomprehensible.

Comment: thank you for all your constructive comments and I will take each notes, and after work I will try it at home (cannot install anything in the office, this is like my research area hahaha.) thank you for your efforts to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach which uses an array of structures. This way you can keep as many parameters (related to the question) in the same place:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct {
    const char *question;
    int correct_answer;
    int given_answer;
} question_t;


int main() {

    question_t questions[] = {
        {"how many wings does bird have?\n1) 55\t3) 3\n2) 5\t4) 2", 4},
        {"how many heads does frog have?\n1) 55\t3) 3\n2) 1\t4) 2", 2},
        {NULL},
    };
    
    int number_of_corrent_unswers = 0;
    for(int i=0; questions[i].question != NULL; i++) {
        puts(questions[i].question);
        scanf("%d", &questions[i].given_answer);
        if(questions[i].given_answer == questions[i].correct_answer) {
            number_of_corrent_unswers++;
        }
    }
    printf("number of correct answers: %d\n", number_of_corrent_unswers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for this code. I modified it so it will use characters instead of numbers, however, I tried inserting text before the questions, but I always get an "undeclared" error about the Fn and Ln, first and last names

Comment: you need to define names as c-strings ( char arrays) - **char Ln[100],Mi[100],Fn[100];** then your code __s("%s",Ln); s("%s",Mi); s("%s",Fn);__ will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an *ordered map* data structure. This consists of a *key* and *value* pair. If you are using the standard library, it has an ordered map data structure that runs with an underlying [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) for data storage.

For your example, you could simply use the question number (or any combination) as the key and the resulting answer as the value.

So, to check if the student answered the question correctly, you would input the question key for a look-up and then return the correct answer value. You can then compare this value against the answer chosen.

[Here is the documentation for the standard library ordered map data structure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

A map can easily be pre-populated with the data you have laid out. Just make a function to parse your text file and create a set of key/value pairs inserted into the map. This is a very common usage pattern for programmers. Many software engineering companies add functions like PopulateValuesFromFile(...) to fill in the data for the data structure. It also makes the code look much cleaner because it isn't filled with a lot of hardcoded strings.